# How to apply Brightness control and change text color?

Tags: iphone, html, css, uiwebview

I require to provide the functionality of **brightness control** in my application, Now I implemented this feature but putting a **dark background colored view** over the screen and later altering its alpha value. All works fine till this point. Now I wish to alter the text color from dark text color to white as the brightness is changed thus creating a contrast.

I am loading the text in UIWebView using a formatted string (with some script embedded).The code goes as follows

```
NSString*   strWebViewText = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet...";

NSString* stringToRender = [[@"<style type=\"text/css\">body{background-size: 100%; background-image: url(\"background.png\"); background-color: #FFF; color: #000; font-size: 12pt;}#div1{margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; direction: rtl}</style><script>document.ontouchmove = function(event) {if (document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.clientHeight) event.preventDefault();}</script><div id = div1>" stringByAppendingString:strWebViewText] stringByAppendingString:@"</div>"];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];  
    [webViewMain loadHTMLString:stringToRender baseURL:baseURL];
```

I wish to change the text color to white for higher values of alpha. The following images provides a rough idea about how I change the brightness value. Any html/css snippet to implement this functionality will be helpful.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For brightness you can use this,

UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
mainScreen.brightness = .5;

For textcolor try javascript and integrate it with your code.

span.style.backgroundColor="Black";span.style.color="white";

Comment: ignoring my lack of knowledge about javascript please consider that I wish to alter the textcolor in a range between dark text to white by providing some values between 0-1 or vice versa. Is there any CSS or js attribute that can provide this functionality. at a point where darkness corresponds to .6 I should be able to alter text color accordingly.